# Google Cloud SQL instance connection error

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I set up GCP for App Maker and create instance and make a connection but there's an ERROR: Cannot create admin user in the default Google Cloud SQL instance. How to address this issue? TIA

Comment: Default user for MySQL is root not admin. Check if problem is solved by creating a new user. check link for details. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users

Comment: If the solution offered in the previous comment doesn't solve your issue, try following the steps here [https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#connection] in order to diagnose the connection issue.

Comment: Here is one more article that could help: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053

Answer (score 2):

There is a place in the GCP & AppMaker guide where you are instructed to go to 'IAM & admin' page and add there 'appmaker-maestro@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' account with role 'Cloud SQL client'.

However you also have to add 'Cloud SQL Admin' role.